# To show DOB through Javascript but December month is showing undefined. Can someone correct the code?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DOB</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mons=["January","Febrary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
        var days=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

        var edob=prompt("Enter Date Of Birth (dd/mm/yyyy)");
        var dob=edob.split('/');

        var date=dob[0];
        var mon=dob[1];
        var yr=dob[2];

        var com=yr+" "+mon+" "+date;
        var day=(new Date(com)).getDay();

        var m = mon.split(''); 
        var m1=m[1];
        if (m[0]==0)
            document.write("Date Of Birth: "+days[day]+", "+mons[m1-1]+" "+date+", "+yr);
        else
            document.write("Date Of Birth: "+days[day]+", "+mons[mon]+" "+date+", "+yr);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is running well but only the month is not showing, it says undefined, can someone suggest the changes in the code to get the required month name?

Comment: can you provide the errornous input? it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has issues with months not starting with 1 because you aren't properly subtracting one from the index of the array. To fix that, we can just remove the unnecessary splitting of the map you did in these lines:

```
    var m = mon.split(''); 
    var m1=m[1];
    if (m[0]==0)
        document.write("Date Of Birth: "+days[day]+", "+mons[m1-1]+" "+date+", "+yr);
    else
        document.write("Date Of Birth: "+days[day]+", "+mons[mon]+" "+date+", "+yr);
```

and we can replace that block with a new block that just subtracts 1 from the month so we get the proper index (ex: December is month 12, so subtract one to grab the 11th index from the months array):

```
document.write("Date Of Birth: "+days[day]+", "+mons[mon-1]+" "+date+", "+yr);
```

Final result:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DOB</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mons=["January","Febrary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
        var days=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

        var edob=prompt("Enter Date Of Birth (dd/mm/yyyy)");
        var dob=edob.split('/');

        var date=dob[0];
        var mon=dob[1];
        var yr=dob[2];

        var com=yr+" "+mon+" "+date;
        var day=(new Date(com)).getDay();

        document.write("Date Of Birth: "+days[day]+", "+mons[mon-1]+" "+date+", "+yr);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```